# Universal covering space for the following topological spaces.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to find the universal covering space for the following spaces.

1. Punctured Disc
2. A solid Torus
3. Union of Sphere in $R^{3}$ and one of it's diameter
4. Torus union a disc

5.

[image]

Any hint,

I know how to find universal covering space of wedge sum of two topological spaces. I learned it from [here](http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2015/12/17/a-recipe-for-the-universal-cover-of-xy).

But I don't have any idea for the above mentioned spaces, How should I proceed ?

Comment: For 5, concider an infinite spiral such that on each floor, you attach the "straight-line segment + disc" to it... Can you use similar ideas for the others?

Comment: @PeterFranek I have the following idea for solid torus: It is homeomorphic to $D^{2}\times S^{1}$, So the universal covering space should (will ) be $D^{2}\times R$.

Comment: Yes, but to see the covering map, it may be easier to visualize this as a "solid helix"

Comment: @PeterFranek What I guess for Torus union a disc is the following: In $R^{2}$ plane, at integer points attach disc.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you now. I guess the disc is attached to the torus so that it filles a hole inside (or not?). Then the covering may be visualized as the boundary of the "solid helix" where on each floor, you fill it with the disc.

Comment: @PeterFranek For punctured disc: It is homeomorphic to $S^{1}\times R$ (using the fact that plane with one point removed is homeomorphic to $S^{1}\times R$). So covering space is $R\times R$

Comment: Your question is not totally clear. Up to homeomorphism yes, it will be the plane in this case. Up to homotopy equivalence, it will always be a point. I thought you want to construct it explicitely together with the covering map.

Comment: @PeterFranek I want to construct it explicitly. You are right.